# Nice and Simple Floating to Fixed Conversion?

Tags: floating-point, fixed-point

I've bee looking for a nice simple way to convert floating to 0.32 fixed.
Has anybody out there some links or papers which are helpful?

Comment: Care to specify the programming language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 2**32 and use a normal convert to integer.

If you need to handle out-of-range values in some specific manner, that may complicate things somewhat; more often than not they can either be ignored or simply clamped before converting.